# I get an error message when I am playing a playlist in Audacious 3.8.2

Tags: 14.04, audacious

When I am playing a playlist in Audacious 3.8.2 I get this error message.[image]

Where is the 'console' and why is this happening? It doesn't matter if the source is my SSD or the ext HDD where all media files are stored. I am running 14.04 LTS

Comment: Did you move the files since you put them into Audacious?

Comment: no, this just pops up when playing a playlist, from the ext HDD. I don't understand what 'error in reading the metadata' means. Because if I click on the next song, the playlist starts playing again--nothing has moved. At the end the message says to 'check the console for details'  What console?

Answer (score 0):

I Don't know what "console" is either.However,you can try going into Disks utility and check the settings on whatever hard drive you are dealing with.There is a setting that decides whether to spin down the (spinning)disk when idle.Of course this does not apply to the boot drive or any other SSD,so that part is a mystery to me.Sorry.